# Show a Notification in Rails after updating a Model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to use the ActiveRecord Callbacks

- before_create
- after_create
- before_save
- after_save
- before_destroy
- after_destroy

to display notifications using jquery to the user?

Can someone provide an example??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the responsibility of the model to comunicate back to the view. In my opinion this should be handled in the controller, not the model. The controller could look like:

```
respond_to :json
def create
  if @page.save
    respond_with {:message => "Aye Okay!"}
  else
    respond_with {:message => "Oops, something went wrong."}
  end
end
```

The destroy and before create cases could follow the same idea: check manually in the controller and send the message from there.

Not exactly what you asked but I think you should keep them separated.

Comment: So the next question is: Where to use those callbacks?

Comment: The code above should go in the controller you need. Suppose you want to update the UI via ajax when creating a post you could add the snippet above in the post_controller.rb. Now send the request to the create action of the post controller and parse the response in your JQuery code. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I mean where the ActiveRecord Callsacks are useful?

Comment: Ah, sorry. They are useful if you need specific actions before executing the create, destroy or save actions. Suppose you want to give users points every time they post a comment. You **could** update the points in the before_create callback of the comment model (note: there are other ways to do this, this is only *a* solution).